# When should I drink protein powder, in the morning or at night, before meal or after meal?

Tags: diet, nutrition, protein

How can  I maximize its utility? When should I drink protein powder, in the morning or at night, before meal or after meal?

Comment: Check out the answers to [this question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4788/taking-protein-right-before-the-workout) about taking protein before a workout.

Answer (score 4):

Protein powder is a *[supplement](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/4066/1771)* meant to be used when eating a protein-rich meal is not feasible. Generally the best time for protein supplementation is immediately after a workout.